# Provision list view for discussion board

Tags: web-part, site-definition, web-template, provisioning, onet

I have provisioned a publishing page through a feature and andded an instance of a discussion board web part to the home page, this works fine. How can I make sure the web part chrome is set to TitleOnly?

```
<View List="Lists/Discussion" BaseViewID="3" WebPartZoneID="WebPartZone2" DisplayName="Discussion"/>
```

I have a document Library and it works fine but privioning the discussion board the same way results in a unknown error

```
<View List="Documents" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="WebPartZone1">
     <![CDATA[
          <webParts>
              <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                  <metaData>
                      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                  </metaData>
                  <data>
                      <properties>
                          <property name="Title" type="string">Documents</property>
                          <property name="DisableViewSelectorMenu" type="bool">True</property>
                          <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
                          <property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>
                          <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
                      </properties>
                  </data>
              </webPart>
          </webParts>
      ]]>
   </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

When provisioning `Discussion Board`  it is required to specify `ContentTypeID` attribute for `View` element as demonstrated below:

```
<View List="Lists/Discussion" 
      BaseViewID="3" 
      WebPartZoneID="WebPartZone2" 
      DisplayName="Discussion" 
      ContentTypeID="0x012001" />
```

where ContentTypeID value is set to `0x012001 (RootOfList)`

Answer (score 0):

My code was actually working correctly my issue ended up being that my pages were being provisioned before my list was actually available.

The pages were in a separate module that was being deployed as a feature which was included in a custom site definition, the solution was to move the pages into the same module as the site definition and deploy the pages withing the module element of the site definition onet.xml.